# NETCORE MVC - How to work with nested, multi-parameterized routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-routing

Looking for best practices when working with nested routes in .NET Core MVC.

Let's say `CampusController.cs` works with a base model:

```
[Route("api/campus/")]
public class CampusController : Controller
{
    ...
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{campusId}")]
    public IActionResult GetCampusInfo ([FromQuery]int campusId) { ... }
}
```

And `BuildingController.cs` works with a child model:

```
[Route("api/campus/{campusId}/building")]
public class BuildingController : Controller
{
    ...
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{buildingId}")]
    public IActionResult GetBuilding ([FromQuery]int buildingId) { ... }

    [Route("{buildingId}/")]
    public IActionResult GetBuilding ([FromQuery]int buildingId) { ... }
    ....
    (more Action Methods)
}
```

If `buildingId` maps directly to the database it could retrieved even if the provided `campusId` isn't the parent. To keep the URL clean when calling `/api/campus/{campusId}/building/{buildingId}` I'd like to validate `{campusId}` and return a 4xx coded IActionResult if it's invalid. There has to be a better way than including validation logic in every Action Method inside `BuildingController`.

- Is there a way to cascade multiple Action methods on different controllers? So that a validation method on `CampusController` would be called first and in turn call a method on`BuildingController`?
- Is there a way to have a controller-level verification of `campusId` that could short circuit and return a ActionResult if validation fails?

EDIT: When I refer to validation logic I mean API signals; not the business-logic that actually determines if campusId is/isn't valid.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can also create a custom filter attribute like `[Authorize]` for the whole controller class to validate every HTTP request by making use of database, route values, query parameters, the logged in user, etc.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If using placeholder in the route prefix you would also need to include it in the action itself

```
[Route("api/campus/{campusId:int}/building")]
public class BuildingController : Controller {
    //...

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{buildingId:int}")] // Matches GET api/campus/123/building/456
    public IActionResult GetBuilding ([FromRoute]int campusId, [FromRoute]int buildingId) { 
        //... validate campus id along with building id 
    }    
}
```

If concerned about repeated code for validation then create a base controller for campus related request and have a shared validation method.

Another option is to have a service/repository that can be used to verify campus id and its relation to the provided building id if needed.

Comment: This solution makes the most sense to me as the entire `campus` model doesn't need to be in the `BuildingController` class; rather just a simple validation check need to be preformed. Thanks!

Comment: Why not using FromRoute instead of FromQuery?

Comment: @Sam `FromRoute` is correct. I had just copied the parameters from the OP. it was an oversight on my part. Will update. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you want your users to provide a `campusId` when talking to the `BuildingController`, and your `BuildingController` to validate `campusId` in a DRY kind of way.

If that's the case, you can create an input model for your `BuildingController` methods:

```
public class BuildingIdInput
{
   [Required]
   public int? CampusId { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public int? BuildingId { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can let MVC bind user input to this model.

```
[Route("api/campus")]
public class BuildingController : Controller
{
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("{campusId}/building/{buildingId}")]
   public IActionResult GetBuilding (BuildingIdInput input) 
   { 
      if (ModelState.IsValid) 
      {...}
   }
}
```